# Is it possible to use a comparator to sort a string from "most negative to most positive"?

Tags: string, sorting, comparator

I have a simple comparator as follows:

```
public class RateComparator implements Comparator<String[]>
{
    public int compare(String[] array, String[] anotherArray)
    {
        return array[0].compareTo( anotherArray[0] );
    }
};
```

But this only sorts values as so:

```
-.35
-.65
.10
.20
.25
.30
.65
1.0
```

What my desired behavior is:

```
-.65
-.35
.10
.20
.25
.30
.65
1.0
```

How would I accomplish this? All values are strings.

Comment: could you possibly convert them to floats and compare them that way from within your comparator?

Comment: @BHendricks It's actually an array with tree fields (so an n by 3 array). The other two elements must be strings, so is there a way to make one double and the other arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You could cast to floats and compare float vals.

Answer (score 0):

You could, in the comparator, do something like:

```
public class RateComparator implements Comparator<String[]>
{
    public int compare(String[] array, String[] anotherArray)
    {
        double arrayDouble = Double.parseDouble(array[0]);
        double anotherArrayDouble = Double.parseDouble(anotherArray[0]);

        return arrayDouble < anotherArrayDouble;
    }
};
```

Comment: Eclipse gives the error message: Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a comparator I would suggest you to use simple **Arrays.sort** to short. In this case you need to use double array instead of string array. Find below the sample code

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Testing {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            double[] fruits = new double[] {-.35,-.65,.10,.20,.25,.30,.65,1.0}; 
            Arrays.sort(fruits);
            for(double arrayElement:fruits){
                System.out.println(arrayElement);
            }
        }
    }
```